# Все возможные комбинации пар значений из колонки

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть в таблице колонка "fruits"

```
apple
banana
mango
orange
```

Как можно написать sql запрос что бы на выходе получить (в массиве?) все возможные комбинации пар значений:

```
apple banana
apple mango
apple orange
banana apple
....
orange mango
```

Спасибо.

Comment: `select a.fruits, b.fruits from table as a, table as b where a.fruits <> b.fruits`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT array_agg(CONCAT(a.fruits, ' ', b.fruits))
FROM table as a, table as b 
WHERE a.fruits <> b.fruits
```

либо

```
SELECT ARRAY(
  SELECT CONCAT(a.fruits, ' ', b.fruits)
  FROM table as a, table as b 
  WHERE a.fruits <> b.fruits
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Это же классический `CROSS JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t_1
       CROSS JOIN t_1 AS t_2
 WHERE t_1.title <> t_2.title
;
```